# Trying to train AllenNLP coreference resolution model on ontonotes: gets CUDA out of memory

Tags: bert-language-model, allennlp, coreference-resolution

I'm trying to train AllenNLPs coreference model on a 16GB GPU, using this config file: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/training_config/coref/coref_spanbert_large.jsonnet

I created train, test, and dev files using this script: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/scripts/compile_coref_data.sh

I got CUDA out of memory almost instantly, so I tried changing "spans_per_word" and "max_antecedents" to lower values. With spans_per_words set to 0.1 instead of 0.4, I could run a bit longer but not nearly a full epoch. Is a 16GB GPU not enough? Or are there other parameters I could try changing?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/bin/allennlp", line 8, in 
> sys.exit(run())
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/**main**.py", line 34, in run
> main(prog="allennlp")
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/**init**.py", line 119, in main
> args.func(args)
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 119, in train_model_from_args
> file_friendly_logging=args.file_friendly_logging,
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 178, in train_model_from_file
> file_friendly_logging=file_friendly_logging,
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 242, in train_model
> file_friendly_logging=file_friendly_logging,
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 466, in _train_worker
> metrics = train_loop.run()
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/commands/train.py", line 528, in run
> return self.trainer.train()
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/training/trainer.py", line 740, in train
> metrics, epoch = self._try_train()
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/training/trainer.py", line 772, in _try_train
> train_metrics = self._train_epoch(epoch)
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/allennlp/training/trainer.py", line 523, in _train_epoch
> loss.backward()
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 245, in backward
> torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
> File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/allennlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py", line 147, in backward
> allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.33 GiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 11.69 GiB already allocated; 639.75 MiB free; 13.09 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Comment: Try to run it on Colab!

Answer (score 1):

16GB is on the low end for that model.

When this model receives a lot of text, it will split the text into multiple shorter sequences of 512 word pieces each, and run them all at the same time. That way you end up with a lot of sequences in memory at the same time even when the batch size is 1.

Try setting `max_sentence` to a lower value (default is 110), and see if that works.